# Crear un método que devuelva el numero de grupos disjuntos de un grafo

Tags: java

Tengo que crear un método que devuelva el número de grupos disjuntos de un grafo, lo único que busco es una "guía" o algún consejo para hacerlo ya que no se me ocurre la manera. Dejo aquí el enunciado y una foto del grafo:
Método contargrupos que devuelve el número de grupos (disjuntos) que hay en la red de
“Seguir_A “ (número de componentes conexas del grafo). En el grafo de ejemplo que hay
al final de este documento, pueden verse 3 componentes conexas, que se corresponden
con 3 grupos: [0, 1,3, 4, 5] [2, 7, 9] [6, 8].
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí no hacemos la tarea, vuelve cuando tengas una duda especifica.

Answer (score 0):

En teoría de grafos hay diferentes algoritmos que te ayudan a recorrer el grafo y visitar los diferentes nodos.

Una posibilidad es usar alguno de estos algoritmos iniciando desde el nodo `0` (por ejemplo, usando: [BFS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_anchura) o [DFS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_en_profundidad)) y marcar los nodos que vas visitando.

Una vez termines el recorrido, revisas si hacen falta nodos por visitar e inicias otro recorrido desde uno de los nodos que no visitaste (no importa cual nodo, lo importante es que no haya sido visitado), y nuevamente marcas los nodos que vas visitando.

Este proceso lo repites hasta que ya no te quedan nodos por visitar.

Si el grafo que tienes de entrada es no-dirigido, el numero de grupos disjuntos seria el numero de recorridos que tuviste que iniciar.

En tu caso, al parecer el grafo de entrada es dirigido, entonces debes tener especial cuidado con nodos que no tienen vertices de entrada (por ejemplo, el nodo `2` en tu ejemplo) ya que se pueden volver un caso especial.

Esto es una guía únicamente, espero sea de ayuda!

Comment: Muchas gracias,ya he entendido como funciona y lo he pasado a código gracias a la explicación.